# Flex - why are these methods not found on my Date objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, compiler-errors, flash-builder

I am trying to compile some example actionscript code.   In Flex (Flash Builder 4.6) I imported a project folder (happens to be the PurePDF examples).

In a few places, I have yellow "?" icons when looking at the source files - though there are no warnings or errors showing up for them yet (I do have other errors I am addressing).

This is an example - when I hover the "?" icon, I see access of undefined property getTime:

end_time = new Date().getTime();

Another one, says undefined property getStackTrace()

catch ( e: Error )
            {
                trace( e.getStackTrace() );
            }

I cleaned up the errors I mentioned, and these yellow "?" marks still appear when viewing the code.   There are no warnings or errors in the 'problems' window, but these question marks I describe are still there.   Even if I close the file and clean the project and re-open the file.

Comment: Do you have problems with the getTime() and getStackTrace() methods in other projects as well?

Comment: Yes (and no!), that seems to be the case now.  In a totally different workspace, I have an air app that compiles fine, with no errors or warnings.   I just noticed in one of my source files I had a yellow "?".   It was on "var aboutWindow:AboutWindow = new AboutWindow();  aboutWindow.open(true);"  AboutWindow is a "s:Window" component in my project.  Everything compiled fine and worked fine though.   Even stranger is the "?" is not there TODAY  (it was there yesterday)!

Comment: i'm seeing this too.  seems that some things were broken in FB4.6.  sorry i don't have an answer for you tho...

Answer (score 0):

It seams an issue with Falsh Builder. Anyway to get over it use:

```
new Date().time
```

instead of

```
new Date().getTime()
```

Answer (score -2):

getTime() is a method of the Date class;
getStackTrace() is a method of the Error class.

Make sure you have imported these two top classes:

```
import Error
import Date
```

Comment: 1. It is not necessary to import top-level classes. 2. This doesn't solve the problem.